# wordpress meta query with multiple meta condition causing a load on server and slows down the server..!

Tags: meta-query

I am writing a meta query with multiple conditions i want to check the conditions one by one it is working fine on the localhost but on the server it is affection and the server slows down and causing a page to refresh continuously. this query is running continuously on the server.

Here is the query :-

```
$meta_conditions = array();
$meta_conditions = array('relation' => 'AND');

$meta_conditions[] = array(
    'key' => 'gender',
    'value' => $pref_user_gender,
    'compare' => '='
);

$meta_conditions[] = array(
    'key' => 'user_account_status',
    'value' => 'active',
    'compare' => '=',
);
if ($pref_age_check == 'true') {
    $meta_conditions[] = array(
        'key' => 'age',
        'value' => array($pref_min_age, $pref_max_age),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    );
}

if ($pref_height_check == 'true') {
    $meta_conditions[] = array(
        'key' => 'height_member',
        'value' => array($pref_min_height, $pref_max_height),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    );
}

if ($pref_marital_status_check == 'true') {

    if (count($search_marital_status) > 0) {
        $meta_conditions[] = array(
            'key' => 'marital_status',
            'value' => $search_marital_status,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        );
    }


}

if ($pref_religion_check == 'true') {
    if (count($search_religion) > 0) {
        $meta_conditions[] = array(
            'key' => 'religion',
            'value' => $search_religion,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        );

    }

}


if ($pref_community_check == 'true') {

    if (count($search_community) > 0) {
        $meta_conditions[] = array(
            'key' => 'community',
            'value' => $search_community,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        );
    }

}

/*if ($pref_language_check == 'true') {
    if (count($search_languages) > 0) {
        $meta_conditions[] = array(
            'key' => 'member_language',
            'value' => $search_languages,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        );

    }

}*/

if ($pref_state_check == 'true') {

    if (count($search_states) > 0) {
        $meta_conditions[] = array(
            'key' => 'state',
            'value' => $search_states,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        );

    }

}

if ($pref_education_check == 'true') {

    if (count($search_education > 0)) {
        $meta_conditions[] = array(
            'key' => 'education',
            'value' => $search_education,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        );
    }

}

if ($pref_diet_check == 'true') {

    if (count($search_diet) > 0) {
        $meta_conditions[] = array(
            'key' => 'diet',
            'value' => $search_diet,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        );
    }

}


if ($pref_drinking_check == 'true') {

    if (count($search_drinking) > 0) {
        $meta_conditions[] = array(
            'key' => 'drinking',
            'value' => $search_drinking,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        );

    }

}

if ($pref_smoking_check == 'true') {

    if (count($search_smoking) > 0) {
        $meta_conditions[] = array(
            'key' => 'drinking',
            'value' => $search_smoking,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        );

    }

}

if ($pref_born_us_check == 'true') {
    $meta_conditions[] = array(
        'key' => 'pref_born_us',
        'value' => $pref_born_us,
        'compare' => '=',
    );
}

if ($pref_citizen_us_check == 'true') {
    $meta_conditions[] = array(
        'key' => 'pref_citizen_of_us',
        'value' => $pref_citizen_of_us,
        'compare' => '=',
    );
}

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$search_query_member_post = array(
    'post_type' => 'member_post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'author__not_in' => $userid,
    'post__not_in' => $unmatched_profiles,
    'meta_query' => $meta_conditions,
    'paged' => $paged,
);

$query = new WP_Query($search_query_member_post);
```

Comment: This type of query is just very expensive, because of how meta is stored. Each meta value is stored in its own row in the postmeta table, which means that for each meta key that you're querying by postmeta needs to be joined again. I count 14 joins in your code. That's quite a lot. You should probably consider storing this data in a custom table.

Comment: Do you mean i need to store this data in a separate table rather than in wp_postmeta table??? is there no way to do this with wp_postmeta yes i am storing all the data in wp_postmeta table..!!

Comment: You could throw a *lot* of hardware resources at it to make it tolerable, and maybe make some optimisations by modifying the table, but this is just too much meta to query by. That said, looking closer at the actual query, many of these fields would be better as taxonomies. Marital status, active status, gender, and any Boolean values, for example, would work much better as taxonomies (numerical values, like height, would not). They’ll be much more performant for this sort of query.

Comment: well i have stored all my data to post meta table and i realize that searching with above conditions will not be possible i will again have to recreate custom tables and then store the values over their i guess the WordPress make unwanted inner joins and make the query so much heavy as it does not load the data properly on the server causing the load on the server.

Comment: The joins aren't 'unwanted'. If you store data as post meta then they're necessary for the type of query you're trying to do. Deciding to store this data as post meta was the mistake, not anything WordPress is doing.